# How to incorporate median()-values into table()-function in R

Tags: r

I have collected data from five different countries in `p$studie==1,2,3,4,5`. The age of all patients are known and stored in `p$age`.

I would like to table the median(p$age) for each `p$studie`. I've tried `table(median(p$age),p$studie)`, which gives an error.

Is there a straight forward solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
tapply(p$age,p$studie,median)
```

tapply will split your p$age according to p$studie and perform median on each group. You get back an array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `aggregate` to get the `median` per `studie`.

```
aggregate(age ~ studie, p, median)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use dplyr and do something like:

```
library(dplyr)

p %>%
group_by(studie) %>%
summarise(med_age =median(age))
```

In order to return the median age by group. Additionally there is a correspond ing aggregate function in Base R that could be used

Answer (score 2):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(p)[, .(med_age = median(age)), by = studie]
```